# How To Make Dynamic Category Based Url PHP using Fatfree Framwork?

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

what i want is twitter or face book kind url.
like if i write twitter dot com/Username its direct goes to that user`s profile

in fatfree framework routing is assign like this and its works

```
$f3->route('GET /about',function($f3)
{
    echo 'Donations go to a local charity... us!';
});
```

then passing url like localhost/site/About into browser Address bar
function get called but if i do want to called it dynamically and write

```
$f3->route('GET /@pageName',function($f3)
{
    echo 'Donations go to a local charity... us!';
});
```

then passing url like localhost/site/Nisarg
Its Shows me an 404 error and nothing get called but

```
$f3->route('GET /@pagename/*',function($f3)
{
    echo 'Donations go to a local charity... us!';
});
```

then passing two / like localhost/site/Nisarg/Desai its get called
any ideas what happening?

Comment: If I understand you well, the second example doesn't work (`GET /@pageName`). It should though.. Which version of the framework are you running? Is this the only defined route?

Comment: i am using 3.5.0 version currently stable release.

Comment: And as per documentation this is the only way to defined the route. but still i am new to f3. i wanted lightweight library that support REST concept and MVC both. and at first look i found this f3 and seems good so i did start work on it but i got stuck here

Comment: is it possible to solve this through 404 error page?

Comment: Your routes are correctly defined. They all should work and that's a mystery why the 2nd one doesn't. I advise you to post your issue on the [F3 dedicated Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/f3-framework), which is the right place for debugging such issues. It could be a bug (although it never arised before) or it could be an obscure configuration bit on your side. Also try the same code with the [edge version](https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/) of the framework, just to make sure it's not related to a bug that has already been fixed.

Comment: Thanks For Advise I was just thinking about to report this as a bug. but not know where to report. so thanks for link.

Comment: with edge version it worked. and i did found mistake with my .htaccess file. "Options +Indexes"  was at the end of the file. that i did put at top. and now every URL worked fine. here is the full conversation [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/f3-framework/ejhvrEdIY8w) on google groups

Answer (score 1):

what about having multiple, per-defined-variable, versions like so...

```
$f3->route('GET /@pageName',function($f3)
{
    $this->do($f3);
});

$f3->route('GET /@pageName/@var1',function($f3)
{
    $this->do($f3);
});

$f3->route('GET /@pageName/@var1/@var2',function($f3)
{
    $this->do($f3);
});

$f3->route('GET /@pageName/@var1/@var2/@var3',function($f3)
{
    $this->do($f3);
});

$f3->route('GET /@pageName/@var1/@var2/@var3/@var4',function($f3)
{
    $this->do($f3);
});
```

the do function would then do the same thing for all, but would take into account whether val**n** was defined.

I've seen this practice used in other languages. I'm not sure if f3 has a better approach already built in.

according to the [documentation](http://fatfreeframework.com/routing-engine#RoutesandTokens) though, it seems that you can use either `/@var` **or** `/*`. Both cases may not be supported.

Comment: In this case 1 $f3->route('GET /@pageName',function($f3){}) will not even considered it will shows 404 error and rest of all will work as per url `s depth of parameter. and i want to make first and 2nd both case work. i see documentation but there is not clearly defined that it will support or not.

Comment: I use a separate routes config file, as it makes routes a lot more manageable. I've seen this setup work before, not sure why it wouldn't work for the first condition. do you have it defined twice by any chance?

Comment: no not at all i did check 3 to four times. what i am not able to understand is why 404 error